# How to use android camera on background?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-camera

I want to take pictures on background, tried everything but I cant.

This is my code:

```
public void getEmotion(Context context) {

    CameraControls cameraControls = new CameraControls();
    cameraControls.takePicture();
```

And the CameraControls class is:

```
public class CameraControls implements PictureCallback {

    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraControls() {
        try {
            this.mCamera = Camera.open(1);
            this.mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Mycamera", "CAMERA ERROR");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void takePicture() {
        Log.i("Mycamera", "Taking picture");

        // Clear up buffers to avoid mCamera.takePicture to be stuck because of a memory issue
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);

        // PictureCallback is implemented by the current class
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, this);
    }

    // ---- >>> onPictureTaken --- NERVER CALLED    <<< ---- //
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.i("Mycamera", "onPictureTaken");
        this.mCamera.release();
    }
```

I've already set camera permissions on android manifest, the problem is that onPictureTaken is never called. How can I make develop this correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by 'on background'. But if you are interested in custom camera handling, there is much more involved in it than I can see from your code snippet.

You can take a look / possibly grab and modify the piece of code I put on [GitHub](https://github.com/seanpjanson/AndyCam). It is quite specific to my needs, but if you know how to cut, paste and delete, it may be useful.

Good Luck

Comment: Hello, seanpj, thanks for helping me. I want to do one android service thats captures pictures using the camera. So, for example, the user can be using google chrome or playing games and my services still continues to take and save pictures. Do you uderstand what I want to do?

Comment: I have never tried to use the cam without activity / surface preview ( I think it is not possible ). I'll play with the idea and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you again seanpj. I really need and appreciate your help!!

Comment: Looks like the camera does not work without surface view. You can still fiddle with the demo (set the SurfaceView to zero width/height, make SurfaceView invisible, hide behind something, etc ...). Good Luck